# I need assistance on this JavaScript image display code

Tags: javascript

This is the code I am currently working with: I need to display a starting image (preferably green) and then, every time the button is clicked, the image needs to change to trafficlight and then to the other image which it didn't start as. e.g it needs to go from green to orange then red then back to orange etc.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html/>
    <html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var trafficlight = [];
    trafficlight [0] = " http://4vector.com/i/free-vector-traffic-light-green-    clip-art_117820_Traffic_Light_Green_clip_art_medium.png ";
    trafficlight [1] =  "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/8/1/7/4/11949849782053089133traffic_light_yellow_ dan_01.svg.med.png ";
    trafficlight [2] = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/f/a/2/11949849771043985234traffic_light_red_dan_ge_01.svg.med.png ";

    var num = 0;

    function changepic()
    {

      if (num>=trafficlight.length-1){
         num=0;
      }
      num=num+1;
      document.trafficlight.src=trafficlight[num];
    }

    </script>
    </head>

   <body>
   <center>
   <img src ="http://4vector.com/i/free-vector-traffic-light-green-clip- art_117820_Traffic_Light_Green_clip_art_medium.png" name="trafficlightpic"  width="400" height="400" />
   <p><A href="javascript:changepic();">click here</A></p>
   </center>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: All right ? What is the question ? What did not work as expected ?

Answer (score 0):

`document.trafficlight` doesn't exist. You need:

```
 document.getElementById("trafficlightpic").src=trafficlight[num];
```

instead. And you should change `name=""` to `id=""` in the `img` element. That should work.

Comment: Put num=num+1 before the if statement

Comment: Chek the url of trafficlight[0]. I think theres a mistake. Try debug it yourself. Add console.log("test") at multiple points of your script and observe the browsers behaviour

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Jonas W - you are trying to referecnce the image but using the wrong reference. You can either do it via an id or using the name as you have. Note that if you are using the name then you need to reference it with a [0] after it as I have in the post - this is because getting the element by name will return an array like object - so you need to specify that its the first item in that. Also your image src for the orange light is broken. The folowing works and allows swapping of the src (with the exception that the yellow light image does not display).

```js
var trafficlight = ["http://4vector.com/i/free-vector-traffic-light-green-clip-art_117820_Traffic_Light_Green_clip_art_medium.png","http://www.clker.com/cliparts/8/1/7/4/11949849782053089133traffic_light_yellow_dan_01.svg.med.png","http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/f/a/2/11949849771043985234traffic_light_red_dan_ge_01.svg.med.png"];

function changepic()
{
  var imageSrc=document.getElementsByName('trafficlightpic')[0].src;
  var num =trafficlight.indexOf(imageSrc);
   if (num >= trafficlight.length-1){num=-1;}
   num+=1;
  document.getElementsByName('trafficlightpic')[0].src=trafficlight[num];
}
```

```html
 <center>
   <img src ="http://4vector.com/i/free-vector-traffic-light-green-clip- art_117820_Traffic_Light_Green_clip_art_medium.png" name="trafficlightpic"  width="400" height="400" />
    <p onclick="changepic();">click here</p>
   </center>
```